# Determining audioformat of audio files in Android

Tags: android

Is there a way to determine the audio format of an audio file in Android? On normal java I do it like this:

```
File file= new File(...);
AudioInputStream stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
AudioFormat format= stream.getFormat();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`android.media.AudioTrack`[[1](http://d.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html)] has the following methods to access information about audio data:

- `getChannelCount` to determine the number of channels
- `getChannelConfiguration` to determine if you deal with mono or stereo content
- `getSampleRate` to find out the sampling frequency

and

- `getAudioFormat` to determine if you deal with 8bit or 16bit sample width.

Answer (score 0):

The AudioTrack.getXXX methods you list merely return the values supplied to the constructor. This doesn't solve the original poster's issue.